# How can I specify position of ContourLabel?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Consider the `ContourLabel`ed plot:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]},
   Contours -> {-0.5, 0, 0.5}, ContourLabels -> All]
```

`=>`

[image]

Is it possible to specify the positions of the contour labels (e.g. if I wanted to center all the contour labels in the plot)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hack you can use. Depending on how often you're going to need this particular functionality, I wouldn't depend on it:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}
  , Contours -> {-0.5, 0, 0.5}
  ],
 ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}
  , Contours -> {-0.5, 0, 0.5}
  , ContourLabels -> All
  , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x - y > -0.05 && x - y < 0.05]
  , Background -> None
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

This depends on the fact that MMA will place the labels in the specified region, so the second version of the plot in `Show` is restricted to the region defined by a small strip around the line `x==y`.